# Partial updates to complex C11 atomic types and non-atomic read optimizations

Tags: c, struct, atomic, c11

I think the easy way to describe my question is to demonstrate it in code, so here is a contrived example in C to highlight the issues I am interested in answering:

```
// Just some complex user defined type
typedef struct {
    ...
} state_t;

typedef struct {
    state_t states[16];
} state_list_t;

static _Atomic state_list_t s_stateList;
// For non-atomic reads
static state_t * const s_pCurrent = &s_stateList.states[0];

// Called from external threads
void get_state(state_list_t * pStateList)
{
    *pStateList = atomic_load(&s_stateList);
}

// Only called by 'this' thread
static void update_state(struct state_data_t const * pData)
{
    state_list_t stateList = atomic_load(&s_stateList);
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        // Do some updating on the data
        do_transition(&stateList[i], pData);
    }
    atomic_store(&s_stateList, stateList);
}

// Only called by 'this' thread
static void apply_state(state_t const * pState)
{
    atomic_store(&s_stateList[0], *pState);
}

// Only called by this thread
static bool check_state()
{
    // Check (read) some values in the current state
    return isOkay(s_pCurrent);
}
```

First, my apologies for any syntax errors, but this should get the point across...

The first two functions are pretty straight forward usage of the C11 atomics, namely one thread is reading a value that another one is writing. My specific questions are really regarding the last two functions, apply_state, and check_state, and it really just boils down to whether these are okay things to do.

In apply_state, you can see that it is only updating part of the structure atomically, specifically, the first element of an array. It is my understanding that essentially every element of the _Atomic s_stateList is considered atomic (much like volatile), so the compiler is fine with the atomic_store call, but can this happen while another thread is 'atomically' reading from the object (i.e. in get_state), or is the synchronization essentially equivalent to a locking / unlock **the same** mutex in each call? I could see how it is possible that since it is basically a different variable (well, okay same address, but what if I used states[1]?) it could result in a different mutex being used. Also, what happens if state_t happens to be lock free?

<s>I'm more confident that the check_state function is an okay thing to do here, because it only performs a read on an object that is modified only by the same thread, but I'm wondering if I'm missing anything here. I've just recently discovered that accessing an atomic variable directly (I think via assignment or function argument) is treated exactly like a call to atomic_load() or atomic_store(), so I am wondering if keeping a private reference for non-atomic reads is a worthwhile optimization, or if the compiler is otherwise smart enough to accomplish similar optimization on its own.</s>

Edit: The result is undefined when dereferencing a non-atomic pointer to an atomic value.

Comment: `static state_t * const s_pCurrent = &s_stateList[0];` This is a constraint violation. Not only is the pointer incompatible, it is a non-atomic pointer, pointing to an atomic type.

Comment: Fixed that, but in any case, when the syntax is correct, I get no complaints from the compiler when I assign an atomic value reference to a non-atomic pointer (of the otherwise correct type).

Comment: Compiler doesn't specify the language, and should not be used as a source of Truth. Under 6.5.16.1 §1, in the third paragraph: *and the type pointed
to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right;* Therefor the left pointer must have all qualifiers the right pointer does.

Comment: Your code has undefined behavior, because it accesses a member of an atomic struct: `static state_t * const s_pCurrent = &s_stateList.states[0];`, assuming the pointer gets dereferenced at some point. As I mentioned before, said pointer is missing the atomic qualifier.

Comment: So there is no way to perform non-atomic reads on an atomic variable (at least according to the standard)?

Comment: No. It also doesn't make sense. If you know that the non-atomic read is not causing a data-race, then there is no reason to have an atomic object in the first place. If there is a possibility of a data-race, any non-atomic read on an object would cause undefined behavior.

Comment: I'll have to disagree. There is no problem performing unlocked reads on shared data in the case that the reader is also the only thread that modifies the data, but I can see why this does not fit with the C11 atomic model (the semantics seem similar `volatile`), but I think your point answers my second question for the most part. Any comments regarding the first?

Answer (score 2):

No this doesn't fit into C11's model for atomics, and for good reasons. `_Atomic` is only syntactically a qualifier, semantically an `_Atomic` is a new type. This is reflected by the fact that the standard allows that size and alignement of such types are different from those for the base.

In your case of a wide atomic type, a permitted implementation of the atomic type is to add a hidden field to the `struct` that serves as a lock. Generally, such types are implemented as "not lock-free" that is with some hidden state (within the `struct` or seperately) that controls access to the data.

The standard can only guarantee you racefreeness by stitching together an access model. If you ask your whole data to be accessible atomic (in the sense of indivisible operations on that whole data at once), the model only allows you exactly that.

Accessing individual fields of an atomic object has undefined behavior. That means if your platform had specific properties it could allow you access to individual fields. You'd have to read up your platform's documentation and hope for the best, in particular that they don't change things from one version (compiler, processor, ...) to another.

Comment: Scott had an interesting question. What would happen if you access an non-_Atomic pointer, that points to a, let's say, and object of type _Atomic int. The assignment itself to the pointer needs a cast, because of  6.5.16.1 §1, but the standard doesn't say anything about access. Except for 6.5 §7, that doesn't allow access (it's about aliasing) of non-atomic and atomic types. Since int and _Atomic int are not compatible and 6.5 §7 doesn't have any exceptions for them. Is this correct? (Good answer btw.)

Comment: Access an atomic through an non-atomic lvalue is undefined. What exactly will be going wrong when you do this is much platform dependend, but you can be sure that this is not portable at all. In particular that can have you subtle race conditions that happen very rarely and are difficult to trace. Generally casts in C are not a good idea, good code can do without, bad code usually has plenty.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I have been replacing some locking with atomics in trivial (lock free) cases, and was looking into replacing locks around larger data structures. These were some of the questionable issues that came up. Glad I asked!